# Main Page error of MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have got this error of the maain page. How to fix it?

http://www.hippomocks.com/Talk:Main_Page

```
The revision #0 of the page named "Main Page" does not exist.
This is usually caused by following an outdated history link to a page that has been deleted. Details can be found in the deletion log.
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this isn't the Main Page, but the Talk page *about* the Main Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_inconsistencies):

> Database inconsistencies occur when, for example, primary keys stored in other fields no longer point to a row that exists. This can happen after a database import ends prematurely, for example. In that case, page.page_latest might point to a revision that hasn't been imported, and users trying to read the page might get an error message stating **"The revision #0 of the page named '[page name]" does not exist. This is usually caused by following an outdated history link to a page that has been deleted. Details can be found in the deletion log."**

The maintenance script [findAnomalies.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FindAnomalies.php) can be used to find missing revisions. From CLI on your server, `cd` to the maintenance directory in your Mediawiki directory and run the script. e.g.:

```
cd /var/www/html/wiki/maintenance
php findAnomolies.php
```

And try some extra stuff

The error message you get sounds like in the page table, the entry of the according page points to a non-existing revision. This might be fixable by running the maintenance script [attachLatest.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:AttachLatest.php). This should make the page point to the newest revision again. This would be what I would try first.

If that does not work and you in fact want to delete the page, I would try running the maintenance script nukePage.php. This script allows you to permanently(!) delete a page from the database. Afterwards you can use the script purgeOldText.php to delete unused rows from the text table.

However, note that your database currently is in an inconsistent state; although the scripts I mentioned were partly written for situations of brokenness, there is no guarantee that they can solve this.

Comment: The answer is outdated. There is no such script anymore.

Comment: Of course it's outdated, it's 6 years old.

Comment: indeed that is very old compared to the age of the universe :-) It shows that the WikiMediaFoundation does not deliver stable software. It's a moving target.